# Meaning of 'As opposition to'

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, parts-of-speech

What's the meaning of 'as opposition to' and what part of speech is 'as' in these following sentences ?

1. Zelenskyy visits Washington `as opposition to` Ukraine aid grows.
2. Some homeowners (were) frustrated `as opposition to` Airbnb rentals builds in West Lafayette.[news headline]
3. It is too early to know whether the Israeli-Palestinian conflict will define this generation `as opposition to` the Vietnam War did for many young people more than a half century ago.
4. UK MPs criticise Israel's Jenin assault `as opposition to` anti-BDS bill grows.
5. Ocasio-Cortez says pro-Palestinian demonstrations should be “shut down” `as opposition to` Israeli war crimes grows.

Answer (score 4):

In all the sentences except No. 3, *as* means *while, at the same time as.* Something is happening while *opposition is growing* (more and more people are objecting) to something else happening.

In [3], *as* means *in the same way as.*

Answer (score 2):

In #1, *as* is a subordinating conjunction.  It subordinates the clause *opposition to Ukraine aid grows* to the main clause.

#4 and #5 have a similar construction.  The  subordinating conjunction *as* subordinates the
respective clause after it to the main clause.

#2 is not a complete sentence. It is a noun phrase. *as* means **while** as defined in Merriam-Webster, conjunction,  sense 5.

In #3, *as* means **to the same degree or amount**, as defined in Merriam-Webster, adverb, sense 1.  The sentence compares the two bracketed clauses:

> It is too early to know whether [the Israeli-Palestinian conflict will define this generation] as [[opposition to the Vietnam War [**defined that generation**] for many young people more than a half century ago]].

*as opposition to* is not a constituent in any of the examples.